# React Native group of routes, DRY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native app I have a root stack that depending of user status will show different screens, thing is many of the screens are still the same so I was wondering if there is a way to group all these routes into a single container so I don't repeat myself:

```
{ !root.mapStore.isStatusPremium && root.mapStore.initialInfoLoaded ? 
                <>
                <RootStack.Screen name="InactiveCountdownCard2" component={CountdownCard3} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000  { ...props }/>) })}/>
                <RootStack.Screen name='SettingCard1' component={SettingCard1} headerMode={false} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={false} headerTitle={ I18n.t('settings') } { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsList1' component={TermsList1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsCard1' component={TermsCard1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsCard2' component={TermsCard2} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={true} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="BlogList2" component={BlogList2} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000  shadow={false} sort={true} search={true}  headerTitle={I18n.t('karmeatBlog')} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="BlogCard1" component={BlogCard1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={true} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="EditProfileCard2" component={EditProfileCard5} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={false} headerTitle={I18n.t('editProfile')} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="UserCard55" component={UserCard59} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 back={true} cog={false} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="SuscriptionFinal2" component={SuscriptionFinal4} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000  { ...props }/>) })}/>
                </>
                :
                <>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TAB2' mode="modal" options={{ headerShown:false }} headerMode="none" component={TAB222}/>

            <RootStack.Screen name="InactiveCountdownCard2" component={CountdownCard3} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000  { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='SettingCard1' component={SettingCard1} headerMode={false} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={false} headerTitle={ I18n.t('settings') } { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsList1' component={TermsList1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsCard1' component={TermsCard1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name='TermsCard2' component={TermsCard2} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={true} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="BlogList2" component={BlogList2} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000  shadow={false} sort={true} search={true}  headerTitle={I18n.t('karmeatBlog')} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="BlogCard1" component={BlogCard1} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:true, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={true} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="EditProfileCard2" component={EditProfileCard5} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 shadow={false} headerTitle={I18n.t('editProfile')} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="UserCard55" component={UserCard59} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 back={true} cog={false} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={({ route }) => ({ headerShown:false, header: (props) => (<CustomHeader2000 back={true} cog={false} shadow={false} { ...props }/>) })}/>
</>
            }
```

One of coding principles is not repeat yourself so I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this!

Comment: Create a function which you can call that will return the Screen?

Comment: You could create a stack containing all of the same screens, and then pass it RootStack, although you would have to deal with having nested navigators.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid dealing with nested navigators you could conditionally create your navigator:

```js
export function RootStack({ finalScreenProps }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="InactiveCountdownCard2"
        component={CountdownCard3}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          header: (props) => <CustomHeader2000 {...props} />,
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="SettingCard1"
        component={SettingCard1}
        headerMode={false}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000
              shadow={false}
              headerTitle={I18n.t('settings')}
              {...props}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="TermsList1"
        component={TermsList1}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} {...props} />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="TermsCard1"
        component={TermsCard1}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: true,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={false} {...props} />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="TermsCard2"
        component={TermsCard2}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: true,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000 centered={true} shadow={true} {...props} />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="BlogList2"
        component={BlogList2}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: true,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000
              shadow={false}
              sort={true}
              search={true}
              headerTitle={I18n.t('karmeatBlog')}
              {...props}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="BlogCard1"
        component={BlogCard1}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: true,
          header: (props) => <CustomHeader2000 shadow={true} {...props} />,
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="EditProfileCard2"
        component={EditProfileCard5}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000
              shadow={false}
              headerTitle={I18n.t('editProfile')}
              {...props}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="UserCard55"
        component={UserCard59}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          header: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader2000
              back={true}
              cog={false}
              shadow={false}
              {...props}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      {/*Allows the last screen to be anything*/}
      <RootStack.Screen {...finalScreenProps} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then in App.js:

```js
const LoginScreenProps = {
  name: 'Login',
  component: Login,
  options: ({ route }) => ({
    headerShown: false,
    header: (props) => (
      <CustomHeader2000 back={true} cog={false} shadow={false} {...props} />
    ),
  }),
};
const SubscriptionFinal2Props = {
  name: 'SubscriptionFinal2',
  component: SubscriptionFinal4,
  options: ({ route }) => ({
    headerShown: false,
    header: (props) => <CustomHeader2000 {...props} />,
  }),
};

return <RootStack
    finalScreenProps={
      !root.mapStore.isStatusPremium && root.mapStore.initialInfoLoaded
        ? SubscriptionFinal2Props
        : LoginScreenProps
    }
  />
```